# C++ how to count correctly the characters in a const char?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, concatenation

I have got a const char which is made by concatenation like this:

```
const char *fileName = "background1";

std::stringstream sstm;
sstm << fileName << "-hd.png";
fileName = sstm.str().c_str();
```

My problem is that the following instruction:

```
printf("const char = %s size = %d", fileName, sizeof(fileName));
```

returns:

```
"const char = background1-hd.png size = 4"
```

whereas I would expect that it returns:

```
"const char = background1-hd.png size = 19"
```

For example, the following gives the convenient result (as there is no concatenation):

```
const char *fileName2 = "background1-hd";
printf("const char = %s size = %d", fileName2, sizeof(fileName2));
```

returns:

```
"const char = background1-hd.png size = 19"
```

How to avoid this issue and guarantee that the characters will be correctly counted in my concatenated char ?

Thanks !!

Comment: c tag removed. I don't know C++, but I suggest you use `std::string` instead of `char *`.

Comment: Your last code-snippet does not print what you say it does. You must have gotten confused somewhere. (Maybe you *actually* declared `fileName2` as `const char fileName2[] = "background1-hd"`?)

Comment: In addition to your other problems, this code `fileName = sstm.str().c_str();` gives you a pointer to a tempory string, making it invalid already at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sizeof()` returns the number of bytes the variable occupies in memory (in this case returns the size of the pointer `fileName`).

`strlen()` returns the length of the string (which is what you need).

You could as well try something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    std::string fileName("background1");
    fileName.append("-hd.png");
    printf("const char = %s size = %d", fileName.c_str(), fileName.length());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` returns the size of the variable you give to it; it's evaluated at compile time. The "4" is the size of a pointer on your system. You want to use `strlen()` to determine the length of a string.

Answer (score 2):

The result of `sizeof(fileName)` is related to `fileName` being a pointer, not an array. It literally returns the size of a pointer to a constant character string, and on a 32-bit system, all pointers are 32 bits (so sizeof == 4).

What you should use instead is `strlen` or similar, which will count the characters in the string, up to the trailing null, and return that. The results with `strlen` in place of `sizeof` will be about what you expect.

Side-related, with `const char` strings there is only ever one character per "cell" (actually byte). There are character sets which make for multiple *bytes* per *character*, but packing multiple characters into a single byte is quite rare, at least in C-family languages.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof` calculates the size of the data type in bytes and not the size of its contents (what it points to). In your example you are calculating the `sizeof` `char*` which is 4 bytes on your system. To get the length of a C string use [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strlen/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a distinction in the language between arrays and pointers, even if this distinction seems diluted both by implicit conversions (arrays tend to *decay* into pointers quite easily), and common statements that *they are the same*.

How does this even relate to your code?

Well, a string literal is actually an *array* of constant characters, not a *pointer* to character(s). In the initialization `const char *fileName = "background1";` you are creating a *pointer* variable that points to the first element of the array ("background1" is *decaying* into a pointer to the first element), and from there on the variable you are managing is *pointer* and not the literal.

If you mix this with the fact that `sizeof` will tell you the size of the variable, you get that in a platform with 32bit pointers and 8 bit chars, `sizeof( const char* )` is always 4, regardless of the object that is pointed by that pointer (if there is even one).

Now, if you were treating the literal as what it actually is you would be having a bit more luck there:

```
const char filename[] = "background1";
assert( sizeof filename == 12 );       // note: NUL character is counted!
const char *fname = filename;
assert( sizeof filename == sizeof( void* ) );
```

In real code, you are not a so lucky and in many cases the literals have decayed into pointers well before you get a chance of getting the compile time size of the literal, so you cannot ask the compiler to tell you the size. In that case you need to *calculate* the length of the C style string, which can be done by calling `strlen`.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` has been suggested a number of times already, and for this case it's probably perfectly reasonable.

There is an alternative that will let you use `sizeof` though:

```
char fileName[] = "background1";

std::cout << sizeof(fileName) << "\n";
```

Since you're making `fileName` an array, it has all the characteristics of an array -- including the fact that your later attempt at assigning to it:

```
fileName = sstm.str().c_str();
```

...would fail (won't even compile when `fileName` is defined as an array). I should add, however, that it seems to me that you'd be better off just using `std::string` throughout:

```
std::string fileName("background1");
std::stringstream sstm;
sstm << fileName << "-hd.png";
fileName = sstm.str();
```

In this case, you can use string's `size()` or `length()` member.